# Set autocomplete off for Formik field

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input, formik

To set the autocomplete off for a simple input it must be done like this: `<input type="text" autocomplete="off">`

In this case, there is a [Formik Field](https://formik.org/docs/api/field) and the input looks like this:

```
<Field
  className="my-class"
  name="myValues"
  as={Input}
  placeholder="Write something"
/>
```

and it seems that adding `autocomplte="off"` doesn't work in this case:

```
<Field
  className="my-class"
  name="myValues"
  as={Input}
  placeholder="Write something"
  autocomplete="off"
/>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: use `children` for that

Comment: @ShubhamVerma is it a way to set that property in children?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure where you are doing wrong. You can simply do this:

```
 <label>
              <Field name="picked" value="One" autocomplete="off" />
              One
            </label>
```

According to doc if you don't pass anything it will treat as a input

Here is the demo:https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-khayyam-9mdll?file=/index.js

Comment: You are passing `Input` component which can be written wrong. I am using without `component`

Answer (score 3):

Solution: camelCase.

Instead of `autocomplete='off'`, use `autoComplete='off'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Field
    name="password"
    type="password"
    component={() =>
        <input
            className="form-control"
            type="password"
            autoComplete="new-password"
        />
    }
/>
```

Comment: You should also add some explanation of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add `enableReinitialize` in Formik, It is working for me.